# Sensible et Sensitif

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, suffixes

Quelle est la différence entre *sensible* et *sensitif* ?

En général, quelle est la différence entre les mots qui se terminent en *-ible* et ceux qui se terminent en *-if* ?

Si possible, j'apprécierais des exemples.

Answer (score 5):

Ces adjectifs sont tous les deux dérivés de la racine *sens* par l'adjonction de deux suffixes *-ible* et *-itif*.

Le premier est une variante du suffixe *-able*. Comme lui, il indique l'aptitude, la capacité, la qualité (Latin *-bilis*).

Un capteur sensible est, par exemple, un capteur apte à détecter une faible variation de ce qu'il mesure.

Le second, *-itif* s'applique à un adjectif dérivé d'un verbe ou d'un nom (Latin *-itivus*). Son sens est donc « relatif à ... ».

Un capteur sensitif est un capteur qui se rapporte à l'un des cinq sens (vue, ouïe, toucher, etc.)

Il n'y a pas beaucoup de concurrence entre ces deux suffixes; je n'ai trouvé que deux exemples similaires :

> audible     : que l'on peut entendre
>
> auditif       : qui sert à entendre

et

> punissable : que l'on peut punir
>
> punitif        : relatif à la punition

Amphiteóth a aussi trouvé :

> destructible : que l'on peut détruire
>
> destructif     : qui détruit

et les moins identifiables :

> connaissable : que l'on peut connaître (Lat. Cognobilis)
>
> cognitif          : lié à la connaissance (Lat. Cognitivus)

Comment: @Amphiteóth Merci ! Réponse mise à jour.

Comment: Nice! As a side note (and I'm not even sure if this applies in French?) in English the "-ible" suffix is found in words that came directly from Latin. The STEMS of some "-ible"-words aren't even recognizable as English words (like “EDible”) & most of them require at least some modification (like the missing “E” in “sensible," whose first definition in English corresponds to “sensé(e)/raisonnable/pratique" in French, which causes me much confusion. (Ah ces quasi-faux amis me donnent mal aux TIFS! Tiens, «tifitif», existe-il pour parler des qualités chevelues? But I digress--to be continued ...)

Comment: (continued from above) The suffix "-able", on the other hand was (& is still) used to create adjectives from just about any word/verb that developed in English &/or came from somewhere other than Latin (& that didn't/doesn't already have an "-ible" form). The stems of "-able"-words are nearly always stand-alone words not needing modification. (“Potable” is an exception to this because, although from Latin, it uses “-able” instead of “-ible” for some reason. "Soluble" is another "-ble"-word from Latin that doesn't use "-ible", & it (with its derivatives) is the only "-Uble"-word that I know of)

Comment: @PapaPoule None of the words you cite came *directly* from Latin but most came *indirectly* from old French. The exception would be edible which afaik never existed in French and was created from late Latin.

Comment: Ooops! I stand corrected.  There is (I think), a "rule"/explanation about "-ible" and "-able" (in English) that's based on a fairly clear etymologic distinction between the 180 or so "-ibles" and the ever-growing multitude of "-ables," but now I'm not sure what that distinction is. Would "words that made it to Middle English from Latin by way of Old French" (instead of "came directly from Latin") be close[r] to expressing the distinction? (or are you saying that no such distinction exists in English?) @jlliagre

Comment: And to make these questions French-relevant, is there an etymologic distinction between "-ible" and "-able" in French?

Comment: As far as these suffixes are concerned, there is no significant difference between French and English etymology. Most if not all neologisms are built with "-able". Legacy adjectives ending with "-able" are from Latin "-abilis" used when the associated verb is belonging to the first conjugation group (infinitive ending in "-are") while the one ending in "-ible" are from Latin "-ibilis" and verbs from the other conjugation  groups (infinitive in "-ere" or "-ire"). eg: * Acceptāre* (1st group) -> acceptable, *Accēdere* (3rd group) -> accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Le terme « sensitif » est la qualité de pouvoir sentir; « sensible » dénote une quantité. Par exemple :

« Ce capteur est extrêmement sensible. » → « Le capteur se déclenche facilement »

« Elle est peu sensible. » → « Elle peu affectée par ses émotions. »

« Le système sensitif permet d'éviter des collisions. » → « Le système dont le rôle est de percevoir des mesures extérieures… »

« La peau contient des nerfs sensitifs. » → « La peau contient des nerfs capables de capter des informations de l'environnement. »

Answer (score 1):

"Sensitif" fait référence à une fonction. Ex: Les nerfs sensitifs. "Sensible" fait référence à la faculté de ressentir (des émotions, des stimuli comme le froid, le chaud ou la douleur). Ex: Il est sensible à la douleur des autres. Son point sensible est son orgueil. Ma fille est très sensible au froid.